# Dynamically add images in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I currently have this code that dynamically adds labels in my app. However, I want to accomplish the same thing, however, instead of labels, I want images. How can I accomplish this? I've tried replacing "UILabel" with "UIImage", but nothing is working for me yet.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((xPoint),
                                                           (yPoint1),
                                                           100.0f,
                                                           40.0f)];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%d", Perclick];
[self.view addSubview:label];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadWebPro-Bold" size:21];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
        delay:0.0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
        animations:^{ label.alpha = 0.0; label.frame = CGRectMake((touchPoint.x + 40), (yPoint2), 100.0f, 40.0f); }
        completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                       if (fin) [label removeFromSuperview];
                   }
];
```

Comment: How about using [UIImageViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `UIImage`, use `UIImageView` and set it's `image` property to a `UIImage` object.